# How to get specific value from the textarea?

Tags: javascript, loops, split

I am trying to get specified value from a textarea.

Html:

```
<textarea name="pull">input type="text" name="bd" value="bd" input type="text" name="bd1" value="bd2" input type="text" name="bd2" value="bd3"

</textarea> <br/>

<input type="button" onclick="pulldata()" value="Button" />

<br/>

<textarea name="tor" id="tor"></textarea>
```

JS

```
 <script language="javascript">

function pulldata() {
var raw=document.getElementsByName('pull')[0].value;


var jqn=raw.split('name=\"')[1].split('\" ')[0];
var vals=raw.split('value=\"')[1].split('\" ')[0];


document.getElementById('tor').value=jqn+'\: \"'+vals+'\"\,'; 
};


</script>
```

This code Seems to work the result i get is;

```
bd: "bd",
```

But i want to get all `name=(.+?) & value=(.+?)`from the textarea,  without using (name=\")[1] [2]... [n]

loop method is fine by me. How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split `raw` by `"input "`,  then loop through it and use your logic:

```
var inputs = raw.split("input ") 
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // Do what you wanna do, then push it to an array
}
```

Comment: <script language="javascript">

function pulldata() {
var raw=document.getElementsByName('pull')[0].value;
var text="";
var i;
var inputs = raw.split("input ") 
for(var i = 1; i < inputs.length; i++) {

var jqn=raw.split('name=\"')[i].split('\" ')[0];
var vals=raw.split('value=\"')[i].split('\" ')[0];

text += raw.split('name=\"')[i].split('\" ')[0]+ ':\"'+raw.split('value=\"')[i].split('\" ')[0]+'\",\n';

document.getElementById('tor').value=text; 
};

};
</script>

Comment: You're welcome :) please care to accept the answer :)